# NPM install e getting permision denied

Tags: node.js

Hi I am running npm i fs and getting the below error .I am new to the node js please help.
I am running the command as administrator and windows security is also off.Operating system is win 11

```
error errno -4048
40 error [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'] {
40 error   errno: -4048,
40 error   code: 'EPERM',
40 error   syscall: 'mkdir',
40 error   path: 'D:\\'
40 error }
41 error
41 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
41 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text 
 editor or antivirus),
41 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
41 error
41 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please 
double-check the
41 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or 
try running
  41 error the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a directory with name node_modules inside the project folder and now it is working.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't have rights to write to folder `D:\`, as stated in the error message. Please confirm your user can create a folder in that directory.

Another test would be to move your project to your user's folder, then issuing a `npm install` from there.

Comment: mkdir command is working from windows power shell but not npm installs